# Can I use HashiCorpVaultParameterProvider in NiFi to get key/value secret engine version 2 in Hashicorp Vault?

Tags: apache-nifi, hashicorp-vault

Currently I need to use HashiCorpVaultParameterProvider to fetch secret from key/value secret engine (version 2) in Vault.
But the Nifi document mentioned that it can connect to version 1.

So my question is Is there any chance to fetch the secret from version 2 key/value secret engine from HashiCorpVaultParameterProvider in NiFi?
If it is posible, how to config the path in HashiCorpVaultParameterProvider, because I can't google about the example of its path.

This is my vault UI look like:
[image]

Comment: We would need to see the configuration for that "parameter provider". If you can configure mount and path, then the answer would probably be yes.